How to Read Register Map From COM serial port using Modbus Protocol and How to convert register value to meaningfull Voltage value? C#
I have a hardware device(Analyzer) that connects to the computer's COM port.
using a usb to RS485 connector. It uses the Modbus RTU protocol.
I'm trying to read the registers using C# on Visual Studio, I use EasyModbus library to connect the hardware with software.
However, I'm junior developer and I need Complete tutorial or source code for this
How can I've convert these register value to Voltage, Current (etc)

Did you look at the examples EasyModbus provides? Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] showing what you've tried. See [ask] for more information or take the [tour]. Do you have the data sheet for your analyzer? That will tell you the Modbus server address and the registers and their data format so you can interpret the information you read correctly.

As importrandom said, use EasyModbus examples to build the test app.
To get engineering values over MODBUS, you need to know how the communicated device encodes them. The device manual helps to obtain this information.
There are some examples:

No encoding. A MODBUS word register gives you the value in the engineering units. Just use the value.
No encoding. Device sends a value in the floating point number format. If EasyModbus supports it, just use the value. Otherwise, you need to convert the pair of word registers to float.
A word register contains the engineering value e. g. in tens of the engineering unit. Device sends 10.3 Volts as 103. You need to divide the word register value by 10 to get the engineering value.


"No encoding. Device sends a value in the floating point number format." - I would argue that floats are encoded. The Modbus spec only covers the transmission of bits (coils) and 16 bit words (registers); I've seen various methods used to transmit floats (pretty rare to see a 16 bit float; most devices I work with use IEEE 754 binary32 but the byte order varies).

@Brits Good clarification. If fact, floats transmitted by 2 registers is the widely used solution, and the order of bytes should be considered.
